# How do I setup nhibernate to handle this?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I currently have this code.

```
                    tableB = new TableB
                    {
                        TableA = tableA,
                    };

                    List<TableC> tableC = locations.Select(location => new TableC
                    {
                        TableB = tableB
                    }).ToList();

                    tableB.TableC = tableC;

                    tableA.TableB.Add(tableB);
nhibernate.Create(a);
nhibernate.Commit();
```

The above code works but I find it kinda weird that I have do it like this.

I would like to do something like

```
  tableB = new TableB
                        {
                            TableA = tableA,
                            TableC = MakeAllTableCs()
                        };

                        tableA.TableB.Add(tableB);
    nhibernate.Create(a);
    nhibernate.Commit();
```

The collection of tableC's is being made in memory and and when I try to do a create I get

```
not-null property references a null or transient value
```

It seems that it want's a reference to TableB for each one in the collection of TableC. It seems kinda odd to do this seeing that I am sticking in the TableB object. I would have hoped that it would have figured that out and used it as a reference.

Is there anyway that I can do it so I don't need to have a reference of TableB in each of my TableC objects?

Edit Mapping

```
     public class TableAMap : ClassMap<TableA>
        {
            public TableAMap()
            {

                Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
                HasMany(x => x.).Cascade.All().Inverse();
            }
        }


 public class TableBMap : ClassMap<TableB>
    {
        public TableBMap ()
        {

            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
      References(x => x.TableA).Not.Nullable();
            HasMany(x => x.TableC).Cascade.All().Inverse();

        }

    }

  public class TableCMap : ClassMap<TableC>
    {
        public TableCMap ()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
           References(x => x.TableB).Not.Nullable();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say without your mappings and real NHibernate code (where you call `session.Save()`) but most likely you are not saving the new `TableB` objects and also don't have any cascade setting on `TableA.b` (you need one of those).

Comment: Ok I updated to show mapping. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: @chobo2 Seems like you are not setting the references to the parent objects before saving (`TableB.TableA` and `TableC.TableB`).